# I am assigning table data from jquery and I have responsive problem in my table

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

[image]

In the above image shows data shows out of table.

code:

```
 <?php include 'header.php';?>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  td{
    padding: 0;
  }  
  .ol-container {
    line-height: 0.7;
  }
  input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
  input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      margin: 0;
  }
  .container {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="/assets/js/plugins/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   var jq = $.noConflict();
  </script>
  <div class="content-area">
    <div class="bg-white">
      <table id="enquiry_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm" style="text-align:center;">
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                          <th>From</th>
                          <th>TO</th>
                          <th>Date</th>
                          <th>Status</th>
                       </tr>
                  </thead>
                 </table>
         </div>
         </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   jq("#get").click(function(){
               status_form();
               return false;
            });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
       function status_form()
         {    
              var lr_no = jq('#lr_no').val();
                        jq.ajax({
                            url :"https://url/sitecontroller/StatusController/fetchStatus",
                            type:"POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data:{
                              lr_no:lr_no,
                           },
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                              jq("#get").hide();    
                              console.log(data);
                              //alert(data.bilty);
                              if(data.bilty!='' && data.records!='' )
                              {
                           jq('#enquiry_table').append(
                           jq('<tr>')
                              .append(jq('<td>').append(data.bilty[0].from))
                              .append(jq('<td>').append(data.bilty[0].to))
                              .append(jq('<td>').append(data.bilty[0].lr_date))
                              .append(jq('<td>').append("Booking"))
                                );
                    jQuery.each(data.records, function(index, item) {
                    jq('#enquiry_table').append(
                            jq('<tr>')
                              .append(jq('<td>').append(data.bilty[0].from))
                              .append(jq('<td>').append(data.bilty[0].to))
                              .append(jq('<td>').append(item.date))
                              .append(jq('<td>').append(item.enquiry_status))
                            );
                        });
                           }else {
                             alert("Invalid Number");
                           }
                          } 
                        });    
          }
  </script>
  <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

In above code in my table tag I have only headers and the data come from jquery ajax success.
In mobile view table data shows out of table.
I am apply some style in my table but not working.
I am using bootstrap 3 file in my header. 
I do not know where I am wrong in my code.

Comment: add <div class ="table table-responsive"> after <div class="bg-white">

Comment: _In the above image shows data shows out of table_ this assumption is simply wrong - the table gets streched because your content is to long - thats the nature of a table - you have a couple of options here - wrap a div around like faizan said, or remove some columns for your mobile view

Answer (score 1):

Add one more class inside HTML code like :

**Your currently HTML code:**

```
<table id="enquiry_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped
table-sm" style="text-align:center;">
```

Now please add one more **class (this is class: display responsive nowrap)** for display table responsive.
Like:

```
<table id="enquiry_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm display responsive nowrap" style="text-align:center;">
```

And if responsive js and css are not included then first include it.

**This is responsive js.**
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js
**This is responsive css.**
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css

If you want to know more and more, click here https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/className.html